# How should I store HTML tags into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have an input named *comment*. User writes his comment into it and sends it under a post. Something like StackOverflow's comments:

[image]

As you see, there is a `<a>` tag into new comment. And it will be stored in the database like this:

[image]

And when I fetch it again, it breaks the HTML of my website:

[image]

I mean everything after that `<a>` will be a link. I don't want that. How can I prevent that happening?

Comment: You should not be storing markup in a database.

Comment: @Script47 No .. I don't want to allow any tags ..

Comment: if your allowing styled comments, how do you not store markup in a database @duffymo

Comment: well in that case `strip_tags()` and various regular expressions. remember strip_tags() expects valid markup

Comment: *"No .. I don't want to allow any tags"* - Funny, that isn't what the title to your question reads. *"How should I store HTML tags into database?"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- good catch :-)

Comment: @Dagon I feel like I'm being pushed and pulled in all directions. Short legs and long arms make for a lot of drag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No no .. I want to store those tags as string *(not as real tags)*, So I want this output for that comment: `این یک پیام <a> تست است`

Comment: in that case you want :[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: *"I want to store those tags as string (not as real tags)"* - I'm even more confused. You shouldn't be storying *anything* related to tags as strings or as untouched tags. PHP is PHP, HTML (markup) is HTML (markup). Two different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Look, I want to print `<a>` in the HTML .. I don't want the browser translate it as a link ..

Comment: IMHO, it's bad db design/practice.

Comment: @Dagon Sneaky pecker wrecker you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just always wanted to do that :-)

Comment: @Dagon Thank you for that function ..

Comment: I'd like to ask "why" you want to do this and not use standard HTML markup when it is needed. You may have problems down the road. This could easily be done in a loop. I've done what you're trying to do now, only to be editing over and over my db, to the point I had to start over. If you have paths involved and you suddenly switch servers, guess what? One unhappy camper. That's up to you really, I'm just passing on some experience here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, so how should I store HTML in the database? What's the standard way?

Comment: You just don't. You use markup inside your code. HTML does intermix with PHP, just as long as the proper syntax is followed.

Comment: @Dagon What's the difference between the function you linked ([htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: "This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities."

Comment: @Dagon I see. Just can you please give me an example that will be translated by `htmlentities()`, and don't translated by `htmlspecialchars()` .. Actually I like to see an example of their different ..

Comment: how about you test it yourself

Comment: @Dagon that's good, but all my tests have the same results for both functions.. just please give me an example which has different result for them ... then I will test it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to store no tag, then use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and if you still wish to have mark-up then use something like [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/).

**Example**

```
$string = '<b>Hello,<> please remove the <> tags.</b>';

echo strip_tags($string);
```

**Output**

```
Hello, please remove the tags.
```

**Update**

What you are actually looking for is [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
<?php

    $str = 'Hello <a href="">blah</a>.';

    echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Hello <a href="">blah</a>.
```

Comment: upvote for effort :-) as the OP is more than a little confusing

Comment: Just one thing, why did you use `ENT_QUOTES` ?

Comment: Check the flag table in the link I provided for the function.

Comment: Aha I see. just can you please tell me what's the difference between the function you linked ([htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) and [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use what some plugins does on wordpress they change the < and > for [ and ].
To prevent code injection I recomend replacing only the following tags

```
<p></p><ul></ul><li></li><a></a>
```

This is done vía javascript in client side and sent to server vía ajax:

```
$("yourtag").replace(/</g, "[").replace(/>/g, "]").replace(/"/g, "'").replace(/&nbsp;/g, "andnbsp");
```

If you are using php to retreive data from the DB, you need to use strreplace on the column where the html is stored, to change [] with <>, in this way your code will not be break
 
Keep in mind to only allow the tags you want as allowing all kinds of tags open the door to an out security, this is donde on server side languaje.
Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Sanitizing through the client side is not the most reliable solution, also what if JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: That is why I stressed in the end server side language should be used to allow certain tags only.